# what predefined to use for doxygen with Boost.Test macros

Tags: c++, doxygen, boost-test

The Boost.Test framework test macros are confusing doxygen. Is there a way to help doxygen work better with the `BOOST_TEST_*` and `BOOST_AUTO_TEST_*` macros? [ref api page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/test_org_reference.html)?

Comment: Side question: why are you running doxygen over unit-test fies?

Comment: It is for internal documentation of the implementation; not for the typical documentation of a public api.

Comment: For that, I use the [`@snippet`](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html#cmdsnippet) command of Doxygen, such that what is not relevant for your documentation is discarded.

Comment: Yes, I have experimented with snippet too. Thanks for the feedback. Do you have examples of good C++ documentation that you recommend as a model to try and follow?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this [PREDEFINED](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_predefined) setting for doxygen that seems to help:

```
PREDEFINED             = "BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(name)=void name()" \
                         "BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE(name)=namespace BoostTest { class name {public:" \
                         "BOOST_FIXTURE_TEST_SUITE(name,data)=namespace BoostTest { class name {public:" \
                         "BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END()=};}" \
                         "BOOST_CONCEPT_REQUIRES(req,type)=type " \
                         "BOOST_CONCEPT_ASSERT(req)= "
```